# Inserting into certain fields of MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I can't get this to compile properly.

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);
$about = mysql_reaL_escape_string($_GET['about']);
$icebreaker = mysql_reaL_escape_string($_GET['icebreaker']);


$query = "UPDATE '$mysql_database'.main SET about = '$about', icebreaker = '$icebreaker' WHERE username = '$username';";
```

I get the error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''a4396957_users'.main 
SET about = 'testing', icebreaker = 'ice' WHERE us' at line 1
```

Is there something missing in this statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't quote the database name with apostrophes or quotes

```
$query = "UPDATE `$mysql_database`.`main` SET `about` = '$about', `icebreaker` = '$icebreaker' WHERE `username` = '$username';";
```

Use ` instead of '

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = "UPDATE $mysql_database.main SET about = '$about', icebreaker = '$icebreaker' WHERE username = '$username';";
```

Certain objects within MySQL, including database, table, index, column, alias, view, stored procedure, partition, and other object names are known as identifiers..

**The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”)..**

**If the ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode is enabled, it is also permissible to quote identifiers within double quotation marks:**

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax...

mysql> SET sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES';
mysql> CREATE TABLE "test" (col INT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: They should be escaped however, just not with an apostrophe, otherwise columns with names such as `lock` or `order` could cause some issues